# Failed build model due to unable to resolve at least one subnet on ingress-nginx for AWS EKS

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress

Need to deploy ingress-nginx as AWS ALB LB does not allow ssl passthrough, I deployed following https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#aws

Getting bellow error on my ingress controller:

```
Failed build model due to unable to resolve at least one subnet (0 match VPC and tags)
```

On my AWS LB ingress resources I have the following annotations to specific which subnet, security group, do I need something similar for ingress-nginx or I am missing something?

```
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/subnets: APP-SUB-US-EAST-1A, APP-SUB-US-EAST-1B
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/security-groups: sg-0fce858099
```

Ingress class details:

```
$ kubectl describe ingressclass
Name:         alb
Labels:       app.kubernetes.io/instance=aws-load-balancer-controller
              app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
              app.kubernetes.io/name=aws-load-balancer-controller
              app.kubernetes.io/version=v2.6.1
              helm.sh/chart=aws-load-balancer-controller-1.6.1
Annotations:  meta.helm.sh/release-name: aws-load-balancer-controller
              meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: kube-system
Controller:   ingress.k8s.aws/alb
Events:       <none>


Name:         nginx
Labels:       app.kubernetes.io/component=controller
              app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress-nginx
              app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
              app.kubernetes.io/part-of=ingress-nginx
              app.kubernetes.io/version=1.8.2
Annotations:  <none>
Controller:   k8s.io/ingress-nginx
Events:       <none>
Same issue if installing via helm with default ingress true:
Name:         nginx
Labels:       app.kubernetes.io/component=controller
              app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress-nginx
              app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
              app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
              app.kubernetes.io/part-of=ingress-nginx
              app.kubernetes.io/version=1.9.5
              helm.sh/chart=ingress-nginx-4.9.0
Annotations:  ingressclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: true
              meta.helm.sh/release-name: ingress-nginx
              meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: ingress-nginx
Controller:   k8s.io/ingress-nginx
Events:       <none>
```

ingress-nginx-controller error:

```
$ kubectl describe svc ingress-nginx-controller -n=ingress-nginx
Name:                     ingress-nginx-controller
Namespace:                ingress-nginx
Labels:                   app.kubernetes.io/component=controller
                          app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress-nginx
                          app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                          app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
                          app.kubernetes.io/part-of=ingress-nginx
                          app.kubernetes.io/version=1.9.5
                          helm.sh/chart=ingress-nginx-4.9.0
Annotations:              meta.helm.sh/release-name: ingress-nginx
                          meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: ingress-nginx
Selector:                 app.kubernetes.io/component=controller,app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress-nginx,app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       172.20.34.107
IPs:                      172.20.34.107
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               http/TCP
NodePort:                 http  32519/TCP
Endpoints:                10.134.242.144:80
Port:                     https  443/TCP
TargetPort:               https/TCP
NodePort:                 https  31233/TCP
Endpoints:                10.134.242.144:443
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                 From     Message
  ----     ------            ----                ----     -------
  Warning  FailedBuildModel  3m (x11 over 154m)  service  Failed build model due to unable to resolve at least one subnet (0 match VPC and tags)
```

Installed using `controller.ingressClassResource.default=true` as I also have AWS ALB controller.

```
$ helm upgrade --install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx --repo https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx --namespace ingress-nginx --create-namespace --set controller.ingressClassResource.default=true
```

I also tagged my public subnets:

```
kubernetes.io/role/elb  1
kubernetes.io/cluster/my-cluster    owned
```